# Can I call "python -m unittest test_code" by "runpy.run_module"?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am learning unittest of python.

I learned that I can run a test, test_code, by

```
python -m unittest test_code
```

from command line.

Now I would like to run unittest in python script.
I learned "runpy.run_module()" corresponds with "python -m". 
However I could not understand how to give arguments to unittest
in the way of "runpy.run_module()".
That is,

```
runpy.run_module(unittest)  # where should I put 'test_code'?
```

Can I run unittest with test_code with runpy.run_module() in the python script?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways to do it:

```
import unittest

import tests # where my unit tests are at
import tests_copy # where my unit tests are at

# make a collection of TestCases
suit = unittest.TestSuite()

# add all testcases in tests module
suit.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName('tests'))

# add testcase tester1 from module  tests_copy
suit.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName('tests_copy.tester1'))

# add all testcases in tests module
suit.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule(tests))

# add testcase tester1 from module tests_copy
suit.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(tests.tester1))


# run the tests
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(suit)
```

Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html)